# Add inline icon before and after the_content() in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When pulling the_content() in WordPress for a testimonial section, I tried adding quotes (fontawesome) before and after it, but they appear on top and below the content, rather than inline with it.
Here's the code:

```
<blockquote>
  <i class="fa fa-quote-left quotes"></i>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <i class="fa fa-quote-right quotes"></i>
</blockquote>
```

Would anyone know how to concatenate them in order for them to appear inline with the content text?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can achieve it by using CSS

HTML

```
<blockquote>
    <div class="testimo-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</blockquote>
```

CSS

```
.testimo-content:before,
.testimo-content:after {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    vertical-align: super;
}
.testimo-content:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.testimo-content:after {
    content: "\f10e";
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your prompt response Ritz Cool, but unfortunately even when trying your code it would still appear on top and below the content, rather than inline with it.

Comment: Ok, then you have `<p>` tag rendered in html output of `the_content()` function, so you have to add `p` after `.testimo-content` so that it must be like `.testimo-content p`, update and check if it works for you. Let me know if it works

Comment: AWESOME!!! Thank you Ritz, it works just fine. I should have thought about adding the p tag, but having never used such rules on the CSS side I was just confused as per how it all worked.
Once again thank you so much for your help and sorting that out.